# Why does Flash Builder 4 use Flash Player instead of a browser to run apps?

Tags: apache-flex, eclipse, adobe, flash, flash-builder

I've got an old flex builder 3 project that I imported into Flash Builder 4, and I want this project to run its web applications in my web browser. However, the apps persistently run in the Flash Player instead. This is causing no end of problems because of the flash player bug documented at https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-209.

How can I make a project's apps run in the browser instead of the player?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue can be caused by HTML generation being disabled. In the project property panel:

[Screen Shot of the settings http://img685.imageshack.us/img685/1487/screenshot20100422at124.png](http://img685.imageshack.us/img685/1487/screenshot20100422at124.png)

Comment: what version  is this? i am using FB 4 in mac. i cant see this window, every time i search this settings.

Comment: found it. project folder -> right click -> properties -> AS or flex compiler (it changes according to project)

Answer (score 4):

In your debug configurations, make sure that the url or path to launch points to the html file that the swf is embeded in, not the swf itself. You can reach the debug configuration menu by clicking the little arrow next to the debug bug icon... (and probably some other way, but i always use that menu).

Comment: I can see that in the run/debug settings now, but it's pretty weird to me that it's happening at all. I'm creating these run/debug configurations right now, and they all point at the .swf file instead of an HTML file. And yet, for other projects, they point to the HTML file. I want to know why that's happening so that I can prevent it.